# How to resize the video in video view according to the size of the screen?

Tags: android, video, splash-screen, android-videoview

I have a splash activity here i have a video view as its content view. How can I fit the video according to my mobile screen size, and of course the proportion of the view should not be stretched.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
        VideoView videoHolder;
        Uri video;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            try{
                videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
                setContentView(videoHolder);
                video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash);
                videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
                setDimension();

                videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        jump();
                    }

                });

                videoHolder.start();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                jump();
            }

        }


        private void jump() {
            if(isFinishing())
                return;
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:layout_width:match_parent`  and `android:layout_height:match_parent to fill all screen width and height and to avoid video stretching and to maintain the aspect ration you should use a video with dimensions ratio 16:9

check this [link](http://size43.com/jqueryVideoTool.html) for calculating the convenient dimensions

So its better to determine which devices screens you are supporting and use a video with the biggest screen size to avoid video stretching or use different videos in your resources folders

Comment: i just want to set matchparent to width adn height programatically once user rotate device or in landscape mdoe but my code is not wroking

Comment: You can override `onConfigrationChanged` and set layout params for your layout programatically                                                                                 `RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                200);       `                          mMainLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnVideoSizeChangedListener. DOCS:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener.html